# How to properly customize the number of pages in beamer?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, page-numbering

I have 3 questions:

1 - How to start the slide count after the Summary (so that the table of contents counts according to the template header - little ball)?

2 - How to increase the numbering source without changing the slides footer?

3 - How to give a spacing between the numbers and the bar, for example, `1 / 2`

Here's my code example:

```
\documentclass[handout,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages} 


\usetheme{Berlin}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

 \addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
     \usebeamerfont{footline}%
     \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
     \hspace{5em}%
     \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
 }

 \setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=blue}
 \setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries}
 %\setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries, size=\large}

%\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

%
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]


\definecolor{mediumblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.8}
\definecolor{azulwhale}{rgb}{0.19921875,0.19921875,0.6953125}

% Standard packages

\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{fancybox}
% Número de Páginas no Rodapé
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usepackage{scalefnt}
% Setup TikZ

%\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzstyle{block}=[draw opacity=0.7,line width=1.4cm]

% Author, Title, etc.

\begin{document}

\title[Ricardo Ramos de Oliveira] 
{%
  Title%
}

\author[]
{
Ricardo Ramos de Oliveira 
}

\date{

}

\institute[]
{
5th IEEE International Conference X
}

\justifying
% The main document

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
  \vspace{-0.6 cm}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.0cm}
\end{frame}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{frame}{Summary}

  \tableofcontents

\end{frame}

%===========================================================================
% Section One
%===========================================================================

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{1 - Introduction}

\begin{frame}{}

\textbf{1 - Introduction}

The graduates of ICMC's graduate programs occupy prominent positions in universities, research centers, government agencies and national and foreign companies. This impact can be regionally identified, since many of them have become teachers in reputable universities in Brazil and América do Sul and created new research centers and graduate programs, which generates significant contribution to the expansion of education and science.

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{}

\centering
\textbf{Thank you. \\ My contact: ricardoramos@icmc.usp.br} 


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: At least for number two: `\insertframenumber~/~\inserttotalframenumber`.

Comment: What do you mean with "increase the numbering source"?

Comment: Hello samcarter, when I use the code `\setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries, size=\large}` all footer text is increased, I want to increase only the font of the numbering of the slides. This is just missing to solve the whole question.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. How to start the slide count after the Summary (so that the table of contents counts according to the template header - little ball)?

You can use `\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]` for all frames which should not been counted. In your current setup, this would print `0/2` on the first two frames, but you can suppress this with

```
 \ifnum\insertframenumber>0
    \insertframenumber~/~\inserttotalframenumber
 \fi
```

> 2. How to increase the numbering source without changing the slides footer?

I have no idea what this might mean - sorry!

> 3. How to give a spacing between the numbers and the bar, for example, 1 / 2

As [TeXnician already said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361475/how-to-properly-customize-the-number-of-pages-in-beamer#comment891214_361475), use something like `\insertframenumber~/~\inserttotalframenumber`

```
\documentclass[handout,xcolor=table]{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=blue}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{%
    \fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
  \hspace{5em}%
  \ifnum\insertframenumber>0
    \insertframenumber~/~\inserttotalframenumber
  \fi
}

\definecolor{mediumblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.8}
\definecolor{azulwhale}{rgb}{0.19921875,0.19921875,0.6953125}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
    \titlepage
  \vspace{-0.6 cm}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.0cm}
\end{frame}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Summary}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{\thesection - Introduction}

\begin{frame}
    \textbf{1 - Introduction}

    The graduates of ICMC's graduate programs occupy prominent positions in universities, research centers, government agencies and national and foreign companies. This impact can be regionally identified, since many of them have become teachers in reputable universities in Brazil and América do Sul and created new research centers and graduate programs, which generates significant contribution to the expansion of education and science.
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}

\centering
\textbf{Thank you. \\ My contact: ricardoramos@icmc.usp.br} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello samcarter, when I use the code `\setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries, size=\large}` all footer text is increased, I want to increase only the font of the numbering of the slides. This is just missing to solve the whole question.

Comment: @ricardoramos How about just doing something like `\huge \insertframenumber`?

Comment: exactly! But I do not know if there is any average size, I believe that huge is disproportionate.

Comment: @ricardoramos Average size of what? If huge (which was just an example) is too big, you can use any* size you want `\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont` - (* if its available in the font you use, otherwise closed size is substituted)

Comment: Sorry @samcarter, I think I could not explain it right..., I want to increase only the font size of the slide numbers, where I should use the code `\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont`? Could you give me an example, please?

Comment: @ricardoramos For example `\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont\insertframenumber...`

Comment: @ricardoramos Please see my edited answer